# Will a student visa extension refusal affect future visa applications?

Tags: student-visa, schengen, refusal

I applied to extend my visa in one Schengen country but failed to meet the requirements (did not achieve enough study credits and didn't provide a reason).

I am thinking of transferring my credits to a new university in another Schengen country, or just apply to a new program.

Will this refusal affect my future visa application?

Answer (score 1):

If the reason why it has been refused is only due to not enough funds, this refusal won't produce future denials. However, your application is likely to be checked more carefully and you could experience some delays.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old and probably closed to discussion but wanted to leave a reply since it is excatly identical to my case. l have been also refused extension due to lack of enough study credits in Germany.l had reasons though...l was suffering from Major depression and my father was on the last phase of cancer and lost his life during my final semester.lt was during the pandemic which was making things worse, so l could not complete my thesis' field work on time.l was not even asked for the reasons for the extension and just refused.l left voluntarily and tried to complete my study online and now l have been working on my master thesis.l am trying my best to convince my department to complete my study online. lt had been almost 6 years in your case, so l do not know if you managed to get a Visa from somewhere else and transfer your credits but if you could not, maybe you can ask your department again if you can enroll again and complete your study from your home country(if your program is research oriented and you do not have to sit for the exams,but submit assignments-which was my case). As far as l know, when you are refused extension due to lack of enough credits in Netherlands, you are not allowed to continue your study and you are de-registered, but this is not the case for Germany.l have not applied for the Visa yet, although l am planning to apply for visa for my PhD in Poland or UK. But based on my knowledge and my lawyers' suggestions, any study Visa application in the Future may be denied and l do not have a high rate of success for study Visa categorization. But l do not know the details of your case but l would only speculate that gaining study visa would be hard given to our record in Schengen Visa information system.